# IE conditional targeting with ReactJS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, reactjs

I'm writing a web application using ReactJS, and I have a need to target specifically **IE9 and below** browsers to exclude a class from being applied.  Specifically, my client has a custom `<select>` control that they want to use, and on their main website (*which doesn't use React*) they use conditional comments to target IE9- to not apply the custom `<select>` styles.  The problem is that **with ReactJS, there is no way to do IE conditional comments**.  I've done a bit of google-foo, and the best solution I can find is [to inject the HTML directly into the DOM rather than allow React to handle the render](https://nemisj.com/conditional-ie-comments-in-react-js/).

```
<div>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <select>
    <![endif] -->
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    <select className = "customSelect">
    <!-- <![endif] -->
        <!-- OPTIONS GO HERE -->
    </select>
</div>
```

Is there a way to emulate this in CSS only, or has anyone heard of a react plugin that would allow me to do IE conditional checks?

[jsFiddle for example here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjve4h1e/2/)

Comment: Do you have metrics that show what % of your user base is still using IE9 or below? XP shipped with 6 and supports up to 8, but for the most part everybody on Windows 7 has probably gotten the update that installs IE11 by now. While there are plenty of folks with older PCs still running XP or Vista, in my experience most of them have already switched to an alternate browser like Chrome or FF to overcome security/performance/functionality probs with IE8/9. Maybe it's not even worth it? But the way you have it in your fiddle works fine for me (on IE9)

Comment: Our metrics show that we have around 9% of our IE audience using IE9...  So we do have to support it.  We don't have to support IE8 thankfully.

I think on the fiddle you're seeing the non-react area working correctly, but the area in react not working right.  I needed the react portion working correctly, but react doesn't support HTML comments so conditionals don't work right.  The solution is to do some conditional class naming.  @insin is pretty close to what I wound up doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other options:

- [Use conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_comments_in_JScript) to write code which will only run in IE (< 11)
- [Use feature detection](https://github.com/gagle/js-ie-version) to detect IE and its version

Conditional compilation can easily bite you if comments are stripped during your build process, so feature detection might be less painful in the long run:

```
var ie = require('ie-version')
...
var className = 'customSelect'
if (ie.version && ie.version <= 9) {
  className = ''
}
return <div>
  <select className={className}>
  ...
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you recommended another package rather than taking advantage of `document.documentMode`?

`var ieVersion = (document.documentMode ? document.documentMode : 99);`

Comment: Wound up going with a solution similar to this, so I'll mark it as the correct answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
let isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

<div>
  {isIE ?<div>
    Internet Explorer
  </div>:<div>
    Not Internet Explorer
  </div>}
</div>
```

Comment: Providing some description on how the code works helps understand the answer